# CSS 3 - Make the border-bottom solid line thinner

Tags: css

I want to draw a line using CSS 3 and place it under an element. The obvious choice for this is the border-bottom, which I set to solid. The resulting line is a little bit thicker than I want it. Is there a way I can make it thinner?

Edit:

The code. (Sorry, late night sloppiness)

```
    border-bottom: 1px solid #454;
```

Comment: Where is your code? Are you using border-bottom: 1px #color solid ?? Are you using 1 pixel right now?

Comment: The lines separating these comments use `border: dotted 1px;` to appear thinner, as noted by Aron

Comment: Sorry fellas, I actually had it set for 2 px. I dont know how I missed that. In any case, 1 px is a lot like what I am looking for.

Comment: I edited the code. The workaround Aron suggested in his answer did the trick.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please, at least show us your code.

What does your CSS say?

1px is the smallest possible line, as in:

```
border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
```

but you can give the illusion of beeing smaller with blending the border colour to the background colour or using the dotted style.

```
border-bottom: 1px dotted rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
border-bottom: 1px dotted #eee;
border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
/*etc...*/
```

might look a little thinner.

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for a workaround like this. And code is added.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using sass, you can easily use the lighten function e.g

```
$color: #454;
lighten($color, 20%);
```

Adjust the % to suit how light you want it.

Answer (score 0):

`border-bottom: 0.5px solid #ccc;`

you can use values between `0.1  to 0.9` to make it smaller